# Update a table according to the value that is being inserted

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying my best to work it out in vain.
I have a table I created using sql as shown below
[image]

what I want is creating a trigger that changes the balance accordingly.
For example, if purchase_stock value is Purchase, then, I can see the value of balance being 12 for maize. And that of Millet being 2.
if purchase_stock value is Sale, then I need to see the bal of Millet reduced by the value in the Quantity. For my case, Balance of millet will be 1.

Also, I wish to be advised, if I can make the Item a primary so that I can create a trigger to increment the balance of Maize without an error.
For example let me consider a command

```
insert into stock_details ( Item, purchase_stock, Quantity) values("Maize","Purchase",11);
```

Using a trigger, I would wish to see Balance of Maize increase from 12 to 23.

Kindly advise and or give me a solution as I learn more.
Thank you.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most products have their own trigger implementations.)

Comment: I am using mysql, @ jarlh

Comment: You don't appear to have a way of establishing order of events such as an auto_increment column or a timestamp..this is bad news if you ever have to fix your data.